# What does it mean when there is a # infront of CSS code?

Tags: css

What does it mean when there is a `#` in front of CSS code?

```
#display: block;
```

Actual snippet:

```
.center1, .vcenter1 {
  display: table;
  #display: block;
  #text-align: auto;
  #position: relative;
}
```

Comment: in b4 "# means id selector"

Comment: @BoltClock what's `b4`?

Comment: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/in-b4

Comment: You shouldn't say "CSS code" as that is extremely vague, especially considering the # character is a part of CSS selector syntax. Anyway I marked it as a duplicate where you can find the correct answer.